# How can I use the same IP addresses on both the host and guest with Linux KVM virtualization?

Tags: linux, qemu, kvm

I am using KVM for virtualization. My problem statement is that whatever IP addresses I am assigning to host interfaces, I want to use the same IP addresses for the guest also. Is there any way I can avoid this IP conflict?